# List co-occurrence numbers of columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data frame contains 3 temperature values and one target value. I want maximum co-occurrence values in temprature based on target value. 
Sample dataframe:

```
                 Index  Temp 1  Temp 2  Temp 3  Target 


                     1      62      66      52    0.24
                     2      62      66      62    0.28
                     3      50      69      52    0.25
                     4      62      66      62    0.28
                     5      50      69      52    0.25
                     6      62      66      62    0.28
                     7      62      66      52    0.24
```

I want output table:

```
                       temprature         target      counts
                    Temp1 Temp2 Temp3      0.24          2
                    Temp1 Temp2 Temp3      0.28          3
                    Temp1 Temp2 Temp3      0.25          2
```

I tried crosstab (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html), it gives me all combination, I just want max or more than one co-occurrence values. Because my actual data have thousands of rows and 30 columns.

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? If so, please consider accepting one (green tick on the left), so other users know. Or, of course, feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `pivot_table` or `crosstab`, just need `stack` at the end

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Temp1','Temp2','Temp3'],columns='Target',values='Index',aggfunc='count').stack().reset_index()
Out[1109]: 
   Temp1  Temp2  Temp3  Target    0
0     50     69     52    0.25  2.0
1     62     66     52    0.24  2.0
2     62     66     62    0.28  3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way via `pd.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
temp_cols = ['Temp1', 'Temp2', 'Temp3']

result = df.groupby('Target', as_index=False)
           .agg(dict(**{k: 'max' for k in temp_cols}, **{'Index': 'count'}))

#    Target  Temp1  Temp2  Temp3  Index
# 0    0.24     62     66     52      2
# 1    0.25     50     69     52      2
# 2    0.28     62     66     62      3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform **pivot_table** on dataframe separately and **join** them together.

Here's how I did it.

```
`df = pd.DataFrame({'Temp1':[62,62,50,62,50,62,62],
    'Temp2':[66,66,69,66,69,66,66],
    'Temp3':[52,62,52,62,52,62,52],
    'Target':[0.24,0.28,0.25,0.28,0.25,0.28,0.24]})

df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Target'],
    index=['Temp1','Temp2','Temp3']).\
    rename(columns={'Target':'target'})
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,
    index=['Temp1','Temp2','Temp3'],
    aggfunc='count').rename(columns={'Target':'counts'})

df = df1.join(df2)
print(df)`
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4aye.jpg)